# File format b'\xff\xf3D\xc4' not understood. Only 'RIFF' and 'RIFX' supported

Tags: python, signal-processing

I have a problem that when i try to read the wav file in python:

```
fs, audio_signal = read('output.wav')
print('\nSignal shape:', audio_signal.shape)
print('Signal Datatype:', audio_signal.dtype)
print('Signal duration:', round(audio_signal.shape[0] / float(fs), 2), 'seconds')
audio_signal = audio_signal / np.power(2, 15)
audio_signal = audio_signal [:1000]
time_axis = 1000 * np.arange(0, len(audio_signal), 1) / float(fs)
plt.plot(time_axis, audio_signal, color='blue')
plt.xlabel('Time (milliseconds)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
plt.title('Input audio signal')
```

I have an error that it is the title of my problem and i dont know how to fix that. So that i hope someone can help me with this bug

Comment: The error says that the library you are using doesn't support the WAV format, or which ever format is acutally stored in the file. What's unclear about that?

Comment: So how can i fix that? I have used scipy.io.wavfile for reading the wav file and it worked yesterday and now i dont know why it has error =(((

Comment: Seems like problem with your .wav file. Compare header of the file with the one that "worked yesterday", there must be some difference. Header of wave file is 44bytes long